# Android Text Size

Tags: android, arrays

Hello i have a app which makes 3 wheels from 3 different arrays of words i am trying to make the text size of the words in the array smaller can someone point me in the right direction.

I have tried the textsize in my xml but it dosent seem to work so is there a way around this in the java?

Thanks.

```
    public class PasswActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.passw_layout);
    initWheel(R.id.passw_1, new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" });
    initWheel(R.id.passw_2, new String[] { "Four", "Five", "Six" });
    initWheel(R.id.passw_3, new String[] { "Seven", "Eight", "Nine" });



    Button mix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_mix);
    mix.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mixWheel(R.id.passw_1);
            mixWheel(R.id.passw_2);
            mixWheel(R.id.passw_3);

        }
    });

}


private boolean wheelScrolled = false;


OnWheelScrollListener scrolledListener = new OnWheelScrollListener() {
    public void onScrollingStarted(WheelView wheel) {
        wheelScrolled = true;
    }

    public void onScrollingFinished(WheelView wheel) {
        wheelScrolled = false;

    }
};


private OnWheelChangedListener changedListener = new OnWheelChangedListener() {
    public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {
        if (!wheelScrolled) {

        }
    }
};


private void initWheel(int id, String[] values) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    wheel.setViewAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(this, values));
    wheel.setCurrentItem((int) (Math.random() * 10));
    wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
    wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
    wheel.setCyclic(true);
    wheel.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator());

}


private WheelView getWheel(int id) {
    return (WheelView) findViewById(id);

}



private boolean testPin(int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4) {
    return testWheelValue(R.id.passw_1, v1)
            && testWheelValue(R.id.passw_2, v2)
            && testWheelValue(R.id.passw_3, v3);

}


private boolean testWheelValue(int id, int value) {
    return getWheel(id).getCurrentItem() == value;
}


private void mixWheel(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    wheel.scroll(-25 + (int) (Math.random() * 50), 2000);
}
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the kankan open source wheel project? If it's that or something else, you should really specify because, as far as I know, there is no "wheel" in the android API. You shouldn't just assume we know what you're referring to. If you are using the kankan wheel project then you should edit the "`wheel_text_item`" xml and adjust the `textsize` of the `textview`

Comment: I have tried changing that but it seems to make no difference

Comment: lemme see what you changed it to.

Comment: android:textSize="5dp"
    android:lines="1"
    android:text="plain"

Comment: @Matt try changing to a large number like 25 first and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 5):

Assume you are using KanKan Wheel. Actually the textSize is set through  wheelAdapter, not wheelView. I know this is weird, but let's face the facts.

You need use [kankan.wheel.widget.adapters.AbstractWheelTextAdapter](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/trunk/wheel/src/kankan/wheel/widget/adapters/AbstractWheelTextAdapter.java?r=17), extend a subclass, and set textSize after you initialize your wheelAdapter and before set it to wheelView:

```
private class MyWheelAdapter extends AbstractWheelTextAdapter {
 ... ...
}

myWheelAdapter = new MyWheelAdapter(getApplicationContext());
myWheelAdapter.addAll(myWheelList);
myWheelAdapter.setTextSize(18);
// initialise wheel widget
myWheelView = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.my_wheel_view);
myWheelView.setViewAdapter(myWheelAdapter);
```

Hope that help.

Comment: You're absolutely right, you cannot change the textsize through wheel_text_item.xml; you must access the Adapter.  I don't understand why Lux got the check. See my answer for an even simpler solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a code snippet that I use to change the size of the text. It just adds an extra line of code.  It's functionally similar to yorkw's code, but is much simpler.

(For the example, I'm using a NumericWheelAdapter; others work similarly.)  The sample code initializes your wheel in onCreate() like this:

```
WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.my_wheel);
wheel.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 0, 9));
```

To tap in to the hidden Adapter variable, simply change your code to this:

```
WheelView wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.my_wheel);
NumericWheelAdapter w_adapter = new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 0, 0);
w_adapter.setTextSize(5);  // The good stuff!
wheel.setViewAdapter(w_adapter);
```